# Multiple numeric integration with function in integration limits

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

My problem is $\int_{0}^\pi\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2f(x)}} q^{2}\sin(\theta) F(q,\theta,p)\eta(f(x)-q^2/2)dqd\theta dx$, I'm trying to plot this over $p$. Function $F$ is a monster, let us consider something simple, for ex. $F=exp(\theta x^{2}/p)$, $f$ is given (see code), $\eta$ is Heaviside function. I tried following:

```
f[x_] := (1 + Sqrt[x] + x*Exp[-Sqrt[x]])^2 Exp[-2 Sqrt[x]]
R[x_] := Sqrt[2 f[x]]
Plot[NIntegrate[
  Exp[(\[Theta]*x^2)/p]*HeavisideTheta[f[x] - q^2/2]*q^2*
   Sin[\[Theta]], {q, 0, R_?NumericQ}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 
   1}], {p, 0.02, 1}]
```

and got standard invalid limits of integration warning. How to deal with this function upper limit?

Comment: 1. `HeavisideTheta[]` is intended for **purely symbolic** work; for numerics, use `UnitStep[]`. 2. `NIntegrate[]` has a special syntax for variable limits; using the order in your $\LaTeX$ expression: `NIntegrate[(* function *), {x, 0, π}, {θ, 0, 1}, {q, 0, Sqrt[2 f[x]]}]`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. Integration stuck for about 20-25 mins(ultimate gaming PC) for my actual F but all done!

Comment: You don't need the Heaviside \ unitstep at all since you've  bounded the integral so that its always 1.

Comment: Note also the integral over `q` can be done analytically, so you should do that first and reduce the numerical integration to 2d.  ( the example shown actually reduces to 1-d but I guess for general `F` that's not going to happen.)